# how do i add image in button? image with text

Tags: android

hi i want to create image button like this way https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2KsD.jpg    in this url how do i create button like this?  half image half text? please help me  i wanna create exactly same button

```
           <Button   android:id="@+id/MyAccountMiniStatement"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"


            android:background="@drawable/curvedplanebutton"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Mini Statement"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this attribute to the button `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

Something like this,

```
       <Button   android:id="@+id/MyAccountMiniStatement"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@drawable/curvedplanebutton"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Mini Statement"/>
```

By providing the drawable Left, the icon will be placed to the left side of the text and also you can use the background attribute to give the white background to your whole button.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you Use [ImageBUtton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html), I think that will be good for you

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/album_icon"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use [CompoundDrawable](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/815).

Some attributes for Button and TextView:

```
1. android:drawableLeft
2. android:drawableTop
3. android:drawableRight
4. android:drawableBottom
```

And yes use [android:drawablePadding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawablePadding) to give padding between your text and image.

Answer (score 0):

Use Textview and for text and `android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"` for image in textview.

So after using this you can see that your textview is containing image also.

Try below code instead of your button code.

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:text="Hello" />
```

Also you can add drawable to any side.
Top, bottom,right,left.

```
android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```