# how do I minimize space between text and image in button?

Tags: android

this is my code below which shows the image in button is work fine but I want to minimize space between image and button. how do I do that?

please help me how I minimize space between image and text. this is my image URL  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2trZa.jpg

```
<Button android:id="@+id/MyAccountbutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dip"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/handshake"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/curvedplanebutton"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="Payments"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried `android:drawablePadding`? Have already mentioned in my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14152517/379693) on your question.

Answer (score 18):

Play with `android:drawablePadding=" "`. You may need to set a negative value.

Answer (score 5):

you can add Attribute `drawablePadding` and set your value, for example:

```
 android:drawablePadding="5dp";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
android:gravity="left"
```

that should change the text to be on the left, not the center.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `android:layout_width` to `wrap_content`, your `Button` will adjust its dimension to its content and will not try to fill its parent.

If you want your `Button` to fill its parent, I agree with WarrenFaith.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late, but this could help some.

Just change the
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`
to
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

that will fix the view.